# Using Rvest to download a calendar information which changes depending on the inputted date

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to use the rvest package to scrape the release calendar from this website https://www.cso.ie/en/csolatestnews/releasecalendar/

By default the dates show up for the coming 7 days which is just what im looking for however when I use the read_html function from rvest it doesn't appear to pickup the defaults as text and as a result I'm finding it difficult to extract the information.

Any help here would be great.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(xml2)

url <- read_html("https://www.cso.ie/en/csolatestnews/releasecalendar")
test<-url %>% html_nodes('td')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

"https://cdn.cso.ie/static/data/ReleaseCalendar.json" %>% 
  request() %>%  
  req_perform() %>%  
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>% 
  pluck("releases") %>% 
  as_tibble()

# A tibble: 220 × 10
   dateindex releasedate dayname   title         refpe…¹ status sector subse…² subse…³ comment
       <int> <chr>       <chr>     <chr>         <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
 1      5325 20/03/2023  Monday    "Fuel Excise… Januar… Confi… Envir… Energy  https:… ""     
 2      5185 21/03/2023  Tuesday   "Transport B… March … Confi… Busin… Transp… http:/… ""     
 3      5066 22/03/2023  Wednesday "Wholesale P… Februa… Confi… Econo… Prices  http:/… ""     
 4      5475 22/03/2023  Wednesday "Environment… 2020    Confi… Envir… Enviro… http:/… ""     
 5      5475 22/03/2023  Wednesday "Environment… 2020    Confi… Envir… Enviro… https:… ""     
 6      5476 24/03/2023  Friday    "COVID-19 Va… Series… Confi… Peopl… Health  http:/… ""     
 7      5150 24/03/2023  Friday    "Vital Stati… Quarte… Confi… Peopl… Births… http:/… ""     
 8      5151 28/03/2023  Tuesday   "Livestock S… Februa… Confi… Busin… Agricu… http:/… ""     
 9      5068 28/03/2023  Tuesday   "Retail Sale… Februa… Confi… Busin… Servic… http:/… ""     
10      5152 29/03/2023  Wednesday "Crops and L… 2022    Confi… Busin… Agricu… http:/… ""     
# … with 210 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​refperiod, ²​subsector, ³​subsectorURL
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting a little with chrome inspector it seems that the site requests all the data then filter it locally with javascript.

```r
data <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://cdn.cso.ie/static/data/ReleaseCalendar.json")
releases <- data$releases
releases$releasedate <- as.Date(releases$releasedate, "%d/%m/%Y")

print(range(releases$releasedate))
#> [1] "2023-03-20" "2024-02-28"

head(releases)
#>   dateindex releasedate   dayname                                 title
#> 1      5325  2023-03-20    Monday                Fuel Excise Clearances
#> 2      5185  2023-03-21   Tuesday                    Transport Bulletin
#> 3      5066  2023-03-22 Wednesday                 Wholesale Price Index
#> 4      5475  2023-03-22 Wednesday Environment Goods and Services Sector
#> 5      5475  2023-03-22 Wednesday Environment Goods and Services Sector
#> 6      5476  2023-03-24    Friday      COVID-19 Vaccination Statistics 
#>       refperiod    status             sector            subsector
#> 1  January 2023 Confirmed        Environment               Energy
#> 2    March 2023 Confirmed           Business            Transport
#> 3 February 2023 Confirmed            Economy               Prices
#> 4          2020 Confirmed        Environment Environment Accounts
#> 5          2020 Confirmed        Environment Environment Accounts
#> 6     Series 10 Confirmed People and Society               Health
#>                                            subsectorURL comment
#> 1              https://www.cso.ie/en/statistics/energy/        
#> 2            http://www.cso.ie/en/statistics/transport/        
#> 3               http://www.cso.ie/en/statistics/prices/        
#> 4  http://www.cso.ie/en/statistics/environmentaccounts/        
#> 5 https://www.cso.ie/en/statistics/environmentaccounts/        
#> 6               http://www.cso.ie/en/statistics/health/
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>